# How can a reader know the quality of a translation?

Tags: translation

[This question](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/3569) asks about the choice of a word and seems to be in the context of assessing the quality of translations. However, to make assessments of the form suggested by the question. One must have a grasp of the original language. However, often one reads a translation, due to the lack of a grasp of the original language. What can a reader do to attempt to assess the quality of a translation, if they do not speak the original language?

Comment: I don't think there's any way to assess how close it is to the original, without knowing the first language.

Comment: Well, you could read reviews and look at criticisms of the different translations. The best way to know the quality if you cannot know it yourself is to ask someone else.

Comment: Same question on Writing SE, with an answer: https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/30933/28912